# Do I need a business visa with a valid residence permit for China?

Tags: visas, china

I used to work in China till June this year but now work in Singapore. I still have a valid residence permit for China till April 2015. Can I travel to China for business using the residence permit for re-entry or do I need to apply for a business visa?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Nobody is going to check whether you work in China or not.

> Changing Educational Institution or Employer
>
> If you want to study at a
> different educational institution or work for another employer, it is
> permitted to do this without having to start from the absolute
> beginning and get a new visa.  The first criterion is that you must do
> this while the existing Temporary Residency Permit is valid...

Comment: I'm agree that his permit is still valid to enter in China, but copying a phrase from a site (without adding the source) is a bad answer